# The best way to implement Groovy builder for java immutable object

Tags: java, groovy, builder

I have an immutable Java object like the following:

```
public class Entity {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public Entity(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getField1() {...}
    public String getField2() {...}
}
```

I want to add a builder for that class written in Groovy inside my test code. I've tried using the `@groovy.transform.builder.Builder` for that.
Here I can't change the Entity class as its in a prod code, so I tried using the builder with the `groovy.transform.builder.ExternalStrategy` strategy.

```
@Builder(builderStrategy = ExternalStrategy, forClass = Entity)
class EntityBuilder {
}
```

But I can't use it for immutable objects.

So I would like to know what is the best way to implement groovy builders for immutable java objects?

Comment: Since nearly all Java files are also valid Groovy files, why not implement the Builder in Java code?  For a straightforward case like the one above, it would be simple to do.

Comment: Sure, its the way I will choose if don't find a groovy solution. I would like to try it in Groovy just for learning purposes.

Comment: Note that the `Entity` class is not truly immutable unless it is `final`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really a builder, but you could coerce a List to your type as long as it has a constructor which can take the List items as arguments:

```
def entity = [ 'hi', 'hej' ] as Entity
```

This works if your type has a constructor which takes 2 Strings.

As your type has no setters, Groovy cannot guess which parameter has which name, so a builder cannot be generated automatically.

You can, however, write some code manually to achieve some nice code.

For example:

```
@Builder
class GroovyEntity {
    String field1
    String field2

    def asType( Class type ) {
        if ( type == Entity ) {
            return new Entity( field1, field2 )
        }
        super.asType( type )
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
Entity entity = GroovyEntity.builder()
            .field1( 'hi' )
            .field2( 'hej' )
            .build() as Entity
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that there's no Groovy builder transformation that can create a builder for your situation. So you'll have to code it by hand. There are two reasons you cannot use a builder transformation:

1. The fields are not public, so the transformation does not see them, and therefore does not create builder methods for them.
2. The generated `build()` method expects the class being built to contain a no-argument constructor and setters for each field.

To illustrate what I mean, here's a snippet of the builder code generated for a class which meets the requirements:

```
@groovy.transform.builder.Builder(forClass = Person, builderStrategy = groovy.transform.builder.ExternalStrategy)
public class PersonBuilder implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject extends java.lang.Object { 

    private java.lang.String firstName 
    private java.lang.String lastName 
    ...

    public PersonBuilder firstName(java.lang.String firstName) {
        this .firstName = firstName 
        return this 
    }

    public PersonBuilder lastName(java.lang.String lastName) {
        this .lastName = lastName 
        return this 
    }

    public Person build() {
        Person _thePerson = new Person()
        _thePerson .firstName = firstName 
        _thePerson .lastName = lastName 
        return _thePerson 
    }

    ...

}
```